# I want set a custom property in a v-for tag, as the code bellow, but how can I get this prop in `computed` method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want set a custom property in a v-for tag, as the code bellow, but how can I get this prop in `computed` method?

How can I get the custom prop 'data-index' here? Because I want to set class for every item individually by index.
I have tried $attrs.dataIndex, $dataset.index, $dataset.dataIndex, ..., but no one is worked.

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in dataSource" :key="index" :class="classForItem"> 
// …
</li>

computed: {
    classForItem() {
      // How can I get the custom prop 'data-index' here? Because I want to set class for every item individually by index.
      // I have tried $attrs.dataIndex, $dataset.index, $dataset.dataIndex, ..., but no one is worked.
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really clear, but for what i understand you want to get the index of the loop in your computed property. It is not possible with computed property.

If you want to get the index, you will have to move your computed property ClassForItem into the 'method' object and send 'index' as an argument, like this :

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in dataSource" :key="index" :class="classForItem(index)"> 
// …
</li>

methods: {
    classForItem(index) {
      console.log(index)
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, if you want to access the dataset elements, you can use this :

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in dataSource" :key="index" :class="classForItem"> 
// …
</li>

methods: {
    classForItem(event) {
       console.log(event.target.dataset.index)
    }
  }
```